# How do I get this average percentage formula to work across multiple sheets?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, formula, spreadsheet, array-formulas

I have 4 sheets named: STATS, SHEET01, SHEET02 and SHEET03.

SHEET01, SHEET02 and SHEET03 look exactly the same like the picture below but with different dates and percentages.

[image]

In cell A1 of the STATS sheet I have the following formula:

```
=IFERROR(ArrayFormula(AVERAGEIFS(SHEET01!B2:B,month(SHEET01!A2:A),2,year(SHEET01!A2:A),2020)))
```

This formula returns the average percentage of **February 2020**.
This formula clearly only works with SHEET01 and I can't figure out how to make it also take the averages of SHEET02 and SHEET03.

I have tried:

```
=IFERROR(ArrayFormula(AVERAGEIFS(SHEET01!B2:B,SHEET02!B2:B,SHEET03!B2:B,month(SHEET01!A2:A,SHEET02!A2:A,SHEET03!A2:A),2,year(SHEET01!A2:A,SHEET02!A2:A,SHEET03!A2:A),2020)))
```

**UPDATE**

Now using the following query:

```
=query({'SHEET01'!A:B;'SHEET02'!A:B;'SHEET03'!A:B},"select avg(B) Where A is not null and A>=date'2020-01-01' and A<=date'2020-01-31'")
```

This outputs the following error:

> Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: B

Comment: so you want average of all 3 sheets in stats sheet in B column based on A column dates?

Comment: In 1 cell in stats sheet I want the average result of all 3 sheets of a given month and year. So when I change the formula to month 4 and year 2019, I get the average result of all 3 sheets where the date is April 2019.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try in B2 of stats sheet if A2:A contains dates:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, 
 QUERY({SHEET01!A2:B; SHEET02!A2:B; SHEET03!A2:B}, 
 "select Col1,avg(Col2) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1 
  label avg(Col2)''"), 2, 0)))
```

or use only this to get the full summary:

```
=QUERY({SHEET01!A2:B; SHEET02!A2:B; SHEET03!A2:B}, 
 "select Col1,avg(Col2) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1 
  label avg(Col2)''")
```

note that you might need to format dates via **<kbd>`123...`</kbd>** button if your dates will outputted as 4000+ numbers

Comment: Using queries seem to be the solution. See the update I made in my post. Getting an error that the column doesn't exist (but it does!).

Comment: @derrtyones well it doesnt... you are using indirect range with array brackets {} so in query you need to use Col1,Col2... references instead of direct A,B column references - hence the arror you getting